# Changing button background dynamically in thread in Android

Tags: android

I'm developing my first app for Android and its supposed to be a game. Everything is fine but there's one thing I just can't wrap my head around.

In my game's "main" activity (not the first activity which starts when the app starts) I want to have a method which starts a thread which changes a buttons background color/image (go with color because I haven't made any images just yet) for one second then turns it back. I wan't the method to also have an integer parameter which makes it perform this n times. I want to be able to call like `changeButtons(5);` and it turns button x background blue for 1 second then waits 1 second five times.

So practically I'm trying to make a "main" thread which runs during the game and inside that thread I'm going to run this method whenever certain conditions are true (a thread which calls a thread).

So I have 2 questions. The first one is "Is this possible? " and If so can someone show me how to do it (not all of it of course but help me get started at least)?  Especially I want to know if I can change a buttons background color in a thread and if so can someone show me how to write/get me started that thread?

The second question is a follow-up, if you can do this, can you have a like a `boolean b` which turns to true if someone presses a button and the thread can "notice" that change?  For example, if the thread is running and Obama presses button x and b turns "true" in the method `OnClick(View v)` can I, inside my main thead have an `if(b == true){Obama.moon();}` and Obama will moon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can.

In android you can use the Handler class ([example available](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html)) to post actions to the event queue. You can do something like this:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable updateRunner = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // we are now in the event handling so to speak,
        // so go ahead and update gui, set color of button for instance
    }
};
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       while (condition) {
           SystemClock.sleep(1000);
           handler.post(updateRunner);
       }
   }
}).start();
```

This will trigger the `run` in updateRunner each second.

---

Regarding your follow up, it can be done as well (of course :) ). You can for instance implement an observable pattern to the class that handles the button x. When pressed, notify the observers with something like `observers.updateChange(b)`
 where you previously had a `thatClassOverThere.registerObserver(this)` in your main thread.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Patrick! But I'm still a bit confused. The code you first post, should i put it in my onCreate() method? That seems reasonable so it starts instantly! And the button is declared in XML but its also a object in my code through findViewById() so i can read it in my onClick(View v) method. Do I still have to do the observer thingy? And one more thing, when using SystemClock.sleep(1000) does the buttons work in the game still? Like a exit button?

Comment: You can put it in your onCreate, or put a `private void startUpdates() { ... }` around it and call it when you want. You don't have to implement an observer, but I thought you had two classes and an observer pattern can be easier to maintain than public get methods. I'm not sure I understand your last question, do you mean if the thread lives on even though you exit the application?

Comment: Can you please show me real quickly the first thing you say, about the startUpdates() thing? My last question is that I will use SystemClock.sleep(1000) alot, and during that is done, will the user still be able to press buttons? Like for example a exit button which toggles this.finish() ?

Comment: I mean you can put it in a method which you call. so `...` is the `final Handler handler = ...` code in the example. In the example above SystemClock.sleep() is called on a thread different than the one of the gui updates, so you will still be able to click buttons and interact with the gui as you normally would.

Comment: Man you are a hero! Thank you!